# Copying a file off an android device?

Tags: android, file, copy, device

How can I copy a file from some Android app's assets folder, to somewhere off the device?

Alternatively, how can I move or copy an  app so that it is installed on the sd card, not the main rom?

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is any straightforward way to copy a file out of an installed app's asset folder without either rooting the device, or the cooperation of the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to learn about the adb push and pull commands: [adb](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Comment: I am familiar with the use of adb commands.  However, adb does not allow an app to be retrieved this way:.  Apparently it lacks permission to read the directory.


I can push an adb shell and cd to the directory (so it exists), but not use adb to push or pull files from it.

Does anyone have anything that works?

Answer (score -1):

As well, files can be copied using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html)

Comment: Alas, DDMS does not work either.   It does not permit the programmer to browse the /data directory (which is where apps live), on my phone.